# Is it possible to read from CSV into a Immutable Object cleanly?

Tags: java, csv, deserialization, opencsv

I have a simple view that's modeled after some CSV data:

```
@Value.Style(stagedBuilder = true)
@Value.Immutable
public interface MyImmutablePerson {
    String getName();
    Optional<Integer> getAge();
    Optional<String> getAddress();
}
```

I have a CSV file matching the data as:

```
name,age,address
John,10,123 Main St
Jack,11,123 Main St
Jake,12,123 Main St
```

I've been testing with some CSV libraries, but none seem to support reading into the immutable object.

The best I've been able to do is splitting it, and then manually building my object myself

```
record = reader.readLine().split(',')

ImmutableMyImmutablePerson.builder()
    .name(record[0])
    .age(record[1])
    .address(record[2])
```

This example with 3 columns it's fine, but in my implementation, I have a ton of columns and it doesn't feel clean having to construct the object manually. Are there any CSV libraries that support reading the line directly into my Immutable?

Comment: So, you're not looking for just any CSV parser library that can create instances of the model for you, but specifically a library that can work with `@Value.Immutable`?

Comment: Yea, was wondering if there a library that exists to do this cleanly without having to read it into a data object first and then building the immutable. I've looked around some more, and it seems like there might not be a library for this right now.